# Open Layers VectorTile and Google Maps Zoom Issue

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am using the OL react package with Olgm("OLGoogleMaps"). The issue I am experience is that the Google Maps layer is animating when zooming, but the Vector Tile layer does not.

The result is that the Vector Tile Layer loads first then the transition of the Google Maps Layer changes in the background. I want to either disable the transition entirely or have the Vector Tile Layer transition the same way as the map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import GoogleLayer from 'olgm/layer/Google.js';
import { defaults } from 'olgm/interaction.js';
import OLGoogleMaps from 'olgm/OLGoogleMaps.js';

.
.
.

    const [map, setMap] = useState<Map>()
    const google = new GoogleLayer({
      mapType: mapView,
    });

    // Creating Map
    const initialMap = new Map({
      ...mapRef?.current && { target: mapRef.current },
      interactions: defaults(),
      layers: [google],
      view: new View({
        center: olProj.fromLonLat([0, 51.5]),
        zoom: 12,
      }),
      controls: [],
    });
    const olGM = new OLGoogleMaps({ map: initialMap });
    olGM.activate();
    setMap(initialMap);
.
.
.
         // Adding Vector Layer
          const {
            colour: color,
            style,
            minZoom,
          } = details;

          map?.addLayer(
            new VectorTileLayer({
              className: layer,
              source: new VectorTileSource({
                format: new MVT(),
                url: `https://marketintelmaptiles.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/${layer}/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`,
              }),
              renderMode: 'vector',
              minZoom,
              style() {
                return new Style({
                  ...style === 'fill' && { fill: new Fill({ color }) },
                  ...style === 'stroke' && { stroke: new Stroke({ color }) },
                });
              },
            }),
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the Openlayers layer while the Google map is animating.

```
view.on('change:resolution', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(
        gmap, 
        'idle', 
        function() {
            layer.setVisible(true);
        }
    );
    layer.setVisible(false);
});
```

Similar to the updated example in [Can I integrate google map/api with openlayers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264869/can-i-integrate-google-map-api-with-openlayers/53268267#53268267) (which is not OLGoogleMaps but two superimposed maps doing something similar).